# Is copying a file byte for byte using Java equivalent to copying the entire file?

Tags: java, sockets, video, javafx

I am working on a P2P Video sharing application. I am reading contents of the file(a .mp4 video) byte-for-byte using the RandomAccessFile class and I am transferring chunks of these bytes over a network using sockets. On the other side of the network I am appending these bytes to a file using FileOutputStream. The assembled file seems identical to the original when opened with a text-editor. Yet JavaFX tells me that the file is corrupt.

Comment: You can't open a binary file with a text editor (or you can, but it's not a very good idea). Show the code you use to send the bytes, there's probably an error somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

> Is copying a file byte for byte using Java equivalent to copying the entire file?

Yes.

The files should be the same if do the byte-for-byte copying correctly.  If not, there is most likely a bug your code ... somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

**This file should be indentical,** but maybe you don't finish the file properly, maybe there are some extra bytes at the end of the file or there are some missing few bytes. Probably the end of the file is somehow corrupted, maybe by just one last byte.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, the files should be identical, but in most of the cases is not recommended to use byte for byte copying. If you are sending chunks of data, just read directly chunks too.

Also, like others mentioned you should not compare the content of the binary files using a text editor. You can use `cmp`, `hexdump` on linux or [WinDiff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDiff) on Windows .